# How to give line break in div using while loop in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to give br tag or hr tag after div, and my div is inside the while loop. Please check the code below what am I doing wrong.

```
<?php $count =0;?>
<?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)) : ?>
<?php $count++;
if($count%4 == 0) {
  ?><br><hr><?php
}

?>

<!-- Number 1 -->
<div class="col-md-3">
  <h6><?= $product['title']; ?></h6>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="width:200px;height:200px">
     <img src="<?= $product['image']; ?>" alt="<?= $product['title']; ?>" class="img-thumb" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <p class="list-price text-danger">List Price: <s>$<?= $product['list_price']; ?></s></p>
  <p class="price">Our Price: $<?= $product['price']; ?></p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick = "detailsmodal(<?= $product['id']; ?>)">Deatils</button>
</div>
```

[Here I want to give br tag after 4 products show in a div, right now my 5th product showing just after details button. I want to give space between details button and title on every 5th product or when my div will show on another row.]

```
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

[image: Here between the details button & product title, here Nike sneakers I want to give br tag on every 4 product.]

Your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Move your `$counter` increment to after your modulus eval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the conditional after the product div, and your `$count` after the conditional, like this:

```
<?php

$count = 1; 

while($count <= 20) {
    echo "Product ID: $count <br>";
    if($count%4 == 0) echo "<hr>";
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake, instead `$x++;` use `$count++;`

Answer (score 0):

You have so many unnecessary openings and closings of your PHP tag. Take a look at this example that uses all of the results from your MySQL query:

```
// Create a counter to store where we're at
$counter = 1;

// Iterate through each product
foreach($products as $product) {
    // Print the HTML markup
    echo '
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h6>', $product['title'], '</h6>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
                <img src="', $product['image'], '" alt="', $product['title'], '" class="img-thumb" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <p class="list-price text-danger">List Price: <s>', $product['list_price'], '</s></p>
        <p class="price">Our Price: $', $product['price'], '</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick = "detailsmodal(', $product['id'], ')">Deatils</button>
    </div>';

    // Print the line/horizontal rulers
    if($counter % 4 === 0) {
        echo '<br /><hr />';
    }

    // Increment the counter
    $counter++;
}
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://ideone.com/Rf7uNw)

**UPDATE**
After reading your comment, you need to be using the [.card-columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/#card-columns) class to layout your product gallery. Take a look at this example that does not require that you keep a counter:

```
<?php    
// Print the containing card-columns
echo '<!-- beginning of card gallery -->
<div class="card-columns mt-3">';

// Iterate through each product
foreach($products as $product) {
    // Print the HTML markup
    echo '
  <div class="card">
    <img src="', $product['image'], '" alt="', $product['title'], '" class="card-img-top" />
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">', $product['title'], '</h5>
      <p class="card-text text-danger">List Price: <s>', $product['list_price'], '</s></p>
      <p class="card-text">Our Price: <s>', $product['price'], '</s></p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success", onclick="detailsmodal(', $product['id'], ')">Deatils</button>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- end of single product -->';
}

echo '
</div> <!-- end of product gallery -->';
?>
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://www.ideone.com/Ahc3hF)

Comment: @Sarah - Did you run the fiddle? It works exactly as you would expect. Also, if you're using bootstrap why not just create a new row instead of a line-break?

Comment: Yes, I am using Bootstrap 4. Actually, I don't think for this purpose the code is needed because I want when a row is cross col-8 then line break. So I have tried padding and margin on last detail button but it also not worked for me. Create a new row for me maybe work. But on while loop how to create new row after 4 products. here the problem remains where I started.

Comment: @Sarah - Then you need to be using a card-columns for your product gallery, take a look at this fiddle: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GBwEYO?editors=1010. I've updated my post to include how to do this with the proper bootstrap markup.

Comment: Thanks for the great help, David! Exactly what I was looking for. But when I add HD image http://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/AmericanApparel/rsadm304w_mediummarblewash all the things get spoil. How can I fix image frame so that everything will be in the line and in the box?

Comment: I am able to adjust the image size but it gets shrink. style="width:100%; height:100px;" , How can I achieve the fix frame of image without getting image shrink or stretch?